# Is there anyway to get /admin/links.json on Shopify and copy that to a dev store?

Tags: php, json, ruby, api, shopify

As most will know, you can only export / import themes and products via admin which is a real pain setting up site development stores as lot focuses on Navigations and Collections... is there anyway to use the accessible .json data and take that json data from 1 store and import into another (dev store) for example?

I have had a look at Theme Kit and setup, seems good for theme syncing etc... but surely we can by now sync / import such things as /admin/links.json, /admin/collections.json, /admin/pages.json etc...

Would be good if anyone knows of a php script that can manage site syncing from prod to dev or soemthing like that... maybe from CMD on windows command line?